# Test two StreamingOutput are equals

Tags: java, jax-rs

How can I check whether the content of two StreamingOutput are equals ?

The equal() compare the object reference.

Google seems also not to know how to do that, perhaps I am on a total wrong path

```
@Test
    public void testStreamingDemo()
    {
        Stock stock = new Stock("SPY", "hello");

        StreamingOutputDemo instance = new StreamingOutputDemo();
        StreamingOutput expResult = new StreamingOutput()
        {

            @Override
            public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
            {
                PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(output);
                ps.println(stock.getName());
                ps.flush();
            }
        };

        StreamingOutput result = instance.streamingDemo(stock);

        assertTrue(expResult.equals(result));
    }
```

and

```
public class StreamingOutputDemo
{

    public StreamingOutput streamingDemo(Stock st) {

        return new StreamingOutput()
        {
            @Override
            public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
            {
                PrintStream pt = new PrintStream(output);
                pt.println(st.getName());
                pt.flush();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to test if `Stock.getName()` have equal results?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we create a object using OutputStream, we will get a fresh copy of each stream object. hence there is not point in comparing the Stream Objects.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class StreamComparsion {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Test.xml"));
            OutputStream outputStream1 = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Test.xml"));
            System.out.println(outputStream.equals(outputStream1)); // Your Expectation
            System.out.println(outputStream1.toString());
            System.out.println(outputStream.toString());
            System.out.println(outputStream1.hashCode());
            System.out.println(outputStream.hashCode());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

}

Output :

false
   java.io.FileOutputStream@6bbc4459
   java.io.FileOutputStream@152b6651
   1807500377
   355165777